# glmulti with a fractional logit model

Tags: r, glm

I want to fit a fractional logit model with the command:

```
glmfit <- glm(tr1 ~ period + male + stib+ income, 
   family = quasibinomial(link = "logit"), data=mydata)
```

Where `tr1` is a variable that lies between zero and one (including some zeros).

I now want to choose the model with the smallest QAIC value (i.e. testing possible combinations of the independent variables and checking the resulting QAIC values). To do that, I tried to apply the `glmulti` command in R:

```
require("glmulti")
glmulti.out <- glmulti(tr1 ~ period + male + stib+ income, 
  data = mydata,crit = "qaic", 
   confsetsize = 5, fitfunction = "glm", 
   family = quasibinomial(link = "logit"))
```

However, I constantly get the following error and I can't see why:

> Error in lesCrit[sel] = cricri : replacement has length zero

Does anyone know how I could overcome this problem?

Comment: could we please have a reproducible example?

Comment: @Ben Bolker : posted an answer below, but still have an issue with one possible solution - would you know how to fix this by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

```
library(bbmle)
qaicmod = function (fit) qAIC(fit, dispersion=with(fit,sum((weights * residuals^2)[weights > 0])/df.residual) ) 

glmulti.out <- glmulti(tr1 ~ period + male + stib+ income, 
  data = mydata,crit = "qaicmod", 
   confsetsize = 5, fitfunction = "glm", 
   family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

This uses a regular binomial GLM but calculates the QAIC based on the estimated dispersion coefficient.
In the dispersion argument of the qaicmod function you could also put the estimated dispersion coefficient of a full quasibinomial GLM with all variables included (some statisticions I have seen recommend this), i.e. to use instead

```
disp <<- summary(fullmodel)$dispersion
qaicmod = function (fit) qAIC(fit, dispersion=disp)
```

Finally, I also tried using

```
library(MuMIn)
x.quasibinomial <<- function(...) {
res <- quasibinomial(...)
res$aic <- binomial(...)$aic
res
}
qaicmod <<- function (fit) QAIC(update(fit, family = x.quasibinomial), chat = deviance(fit) / df.residual(fit))

glmulti.out <- glmulti(tr1 ~ period + male + stib+ income, 
      data = mydata,crit = "qaicmod", 
       confsetsize = 5, fitfunction = "glm", 
       family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

but that returns the error `"Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "fitfunc""` - not sure how I can fix that...
(The idea would be that this solution would properly refit the model as a quasibinomial GLM and then return the QAIC from that)

First solution above should be OK though I think...